# How do I set up salesforce endpoint for multiple objects in the same java project?

Tags: soap-api, soap, java, workflowoutboundmessage

I am trying to set up a outbound message trigger on three objects. The trigger is to send a soap message to an end point (running on public IP). I got this to work for one object. The issue is when I want to set it up for the second object.  When I try to generate wsdl for the outbound message of the second object - I get a different wsdl from the first one, with the following text different:
EDIT - showing both the wsdl here:
This is my wsdl on Account object

```
           <element name="notifications">
            <complexType> 
                <sequence> 
                    <element name="OrganizationId" type="ent:ID" />
                    <element name="ActionId" type="ent:ID" />
                    <element name="SessionId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                    <element name="EnterpriseUrl" type="xsd:string" />
                    <element name="PartnerUrl" type="xsd:string" />
                    <element name="Notification" maxOccurs="100" type="tns:AccountNotification" />
                </sequence> 
            </complexType> 
        </element>

        <complexType name="AccountNotification">
            <sequence>
                <element name="Id" type="ent:ID" />
                <element name="sObject" type="ens:Account" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
```

and this is my wsdl for Contact:

```
       <element name="notifications">
            <complexType> 
                <sequence> 
                    <element name="OrganizationId" type="ent:ID" />
                    <element name="ActionId" type="ent:ID" />
                    <element name="SessionId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                    <element name="EnterpriseUrl" type="xsd:string" />
                    <element name="PartnerUrl" type="xsd:string" />
                    <element name="Notification" maxOccurs="100" type="tns:Contacts__cNotification" />
                </sequence> 
            </complexType> 
        </element>

        <complexType name="Contacts__cNotification">
            <sequence>
                <element name="Id" type="ent:ID" />
                <element name="sObject" type="ens:Contact" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
```

Seems like there can only be one endpoint for the `notifications()` that is called when the soap message is sent?

Sure enough, I can have the second wsdl in a different endpoint and different listener altogether (which means different war file). But this does not exactly look scalable if in the future I want to configure the outbound message for more objects.

Is there a way to merge all the different wsdl of custom objects into one? Or is there any other way I can go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a readily available way to test this, but you should be able to modify the WSDL to use a `choice`. When the endpoint is called by salesforce, the appropriate type will be selected. You can modify the element as follows:

```
<element name="notifications">
    <complexType> 
        <sequence> 
            <element name="OrganizationId" type="ent:ID" />
            <element name="ActionId" type="ent:ID" />
            <element name="SessionId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
            <element name="EnterpriseUrl" type="xsd:string" />
            <element name="PartnerUrl" type="xsd:string" />
            <choice>
                <element name="Notification" maxOccurs="100" type="tns:AccountNotification" />
                <element name="Notification" maxOccurs="100" type="tns:Contacts__cNotification" />
            </choice>
        </sequence> 
    </complexType> 
</element>
<complexType name="AccountNotification">
    <sequence>
        <element name="Id" type="ent:ID" />
        <element name="sObject" type="ens:Account" />
    </sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="Contacts__cNotification">
    <sequence>
        <element name="Id" type="ent:ID" />
        <element name="sObject" type="ens:Contact" />
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Comment: I updated my question to show both the wsdl. If I add all the 'sObject' elements, what will the notification be called? Doesn't that matter?

Comment: @persistence.xml based on the update, I surmise that the choice element will actually need to be in the notifications complex type instead. Does this help?

Comment: That definitely does help. However, when I generated Java code from the wsdl, I get one `notifications()` method, which takes in both types of notifications as parameters. So I am assuming I examine the values in both, and have an action for both types. In your expert opinion, does that make sense?

Comment: @persistence.xml Yes, you'd have to check the type of the notification and make your decision based on that. You can't otherwise have the same method with different parameters that I know of.